# Unable to create TWO Data Factory Pipeline activities pointing to same Target Dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am looking for a solution to load the data from SQL DW DMVs from 2 different database into single table on one SQL DW table.

I went with a ADF Pipeline activity - which helps in loading the data for every 15 minutes, But I am seeing a issue - when I create two activities into one pipeline in which it has 2 different source (Input dataset) but both loads the data into same target ( Output dataset).
I also wanted to make sure - I build a dependency between the activities , so that they wont run at the same time. Activity 2 starts only after Activity 1 is completed/not-running.

My ADF Code is as below:

```
{
     "name": "Execution_Requests_Hist",
"properties": {
    "description": "Execution Requests history data",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from dm_pdw_exec_requests_hist_view"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                },
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "columnMappings": "request_id:request_id,session_id:session_id,status:status,submit_time:submit_time,start_time:start_time,end_compile_time:end_compile_time,total_elapsed_time:total_elapsed_time,end_time:end_time,label:label,error_id:error_id,command:command,resource_class:resource_class,database_id:database_id,login_name:login_name,app_name:app_name,client_id:client_id,DMV_Source:DMV_Source,source:source,type:type,create_time:create_time,details:details"
                },
                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "ID_Exec_Requests"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OD_Exec_Requests"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                "style": "StartOfInterval",
                "retry": 3,
                "longRetry": 0,
                "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "PRD_DMV_Load"
        },
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from dm_pdw_exec_requests_hist_view"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                },
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "columnMappings": "request_id:request_id,session_id:session_id,status:status,submit_time:submit_time,start_time:start_time,end_compile_time:end_compile_time,total_elapsed_time:total_elapsed_time,end_time:end_time,label:label,error_id:error_id,command:command,resource_class:resource_class,database_id:database_id,login_name:login_name,app_name:app_name,client_id:client_id,DMV_Source:DMV_Source,source:source,type:type,create_time:create_time,details:details"
                },
                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OD_Exec_Requests",
                    "name": "ITG_Exec_Requests"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OD_Exec_Requests"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                "style": "StartOfInterval",
                "retry": 3,
                "longRetry": 0,
                "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "ITG_DMV_Load"
        }           
    ],
    "start": "2017-08-20T04:22:00Z",
    "end": "2018-08-20T04:22:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "xyz-adf_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

}

When I try to deploy this - Its giving below error message:

> Error Activities 'PRD_DMV_Load' and 'ITG_DMV_Load' have the same
>   output Dataset 'OD_Exec_Requests'. Two activities cannot output the
>   same Dataset over the same active period.

How can I resolve this? Can I say - run ITG_DMV_Load only after PRD_DMV_Load is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.

**You cannot produce the same dataset slice from two different activities/pipelines.** To workaround this one you can create another dataset which will point on the same table, but from ADF perspective this will be different sink. You also need to move your second activity into separate pipeline configuration (so you end up with one activity per pipeline).

**You need to somehow order your pipelines.** I see two possible ways:
you can try using scheduler configuration options - e.q. you can use `offset` property (or `style`) to schedule one pipeline in the middle of the interval:
For example, if first pipeline is configured like this:

```
 "scheduler": {
     "frequency": "Minute",
     "interval": 15
 },
```

Configure the second like this:

```
"scheduler": {
     "frequency": "Minute",
     "interval": 15,
     "offset" : 5
},
```

This approach may require some tuning depends on how long does it take your pipeline to complete.

Another approach is to specify output of first pipeline as input of second. In this case second activity won't start till first one is completed. The schedule of activities must match in this case (i.e. both should have same `scheduler.frequency` and `scheduler.interval`).

Answer (score 0):

As @arghtype says you cannot use the same ADF dataset in two active pipelines or activities. You will need to create a second, identical output dataset for the ITG_DMV_Load but you do not have to split the pipeline. You can ensure the second activity does not run until the first is completed by making the output of the first a secondary input to the second. I would suggest something like this...

```
    {
     "name": "Execution_Requests_Hist",
"properties": {
    "description": "Execution Requests history data",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from dm_pdw_exec_requests_hist_view"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                },
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "columnMappings": "request_id:request_id,session_id:session_id,status:status,submit_time:submit_time,start_time:start_time,end_compile_time:end_compile_time,total_elapsed_time:total_elapsed_time,end_time:end_time,label:label,error_id:error_id,command:command,resource_class:resource_class,database_id:database_id,login_name:login_name,app_name:app_name,client_id:client_id,DMV_Source:DMV_Source,source:source,type:type,create_time:create_time,details:details"
                },
                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "ID_Exec_Requests"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OD_Exec_Requests_PRD"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                "style": "StartOfInterval",
                "retry": 3,
                "longRetry": 0,
                "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "PRD_DMV_Load"
        },
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from dm_pdw_exec_requests_hist_view"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                },
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "columnMappings": "request_id:request_id,session_id:session_id,status:status,submit_time:submit_time,start_time:start_time,end_compile_time:end_compile_time,total_elapsed_time:total_elapsed_time,end_time:end_time,label:label,error_id:error_id,command:command,resource_class:resource_class,database_id:database_id,login_name:login_name,app_name:app_name,client_id:client_id,DMV_Source:DMV_Source,source:source,type:type,create_time:create_time,details:details"
                },
                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "ITG_Exec_Requests",
                    "name": "OD_Exec_Requests_PRD"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OD_Exec_Requests_ITG"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                "style": "StartOfInterval",
                "retry": 3,
                "longRetry": 0,
                "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "ITG_DMV_Load"
        }           
    ],
    "start": "2017-08-20T04:22:00Z",
    "end": "2018-08-20T04:22:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "xyz-adf_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```